# Order by fields after searching

Tags: search, filter

I need to order the results of a search query *after* I got back the results. The reason to do this is that I want to make different lists on the same page (with the same results) and I dont't want to search over and over again just to reorder te results. Can I do that? So basically I do this:

```
{% set results =  craft.entries.section('player').search('team:"thenameoftheteam"') %}
```

What I want to do with this result is:
loop

- through the results and order them by `playerPosition`
- show the longest player (lengths are in the field `playerHeight`)
- show the oldest player (birth dates are in the field `playerBirth`)

I could run this query 3 times and order by a different field each time, but I don't think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really feasible without a plugin – fortunately, there's the excellent [SuperSort](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort):

```
{% set results =  craft.entries.section('player').search('team:"thenameoftheteam"') %}

{% set resultsByPlayerPosition = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{playerPosition}') %}
{% set resultsByPlayerHeight = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{playerHeight}') %}
{% set resultsByPlayerBirth = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{playerBirth}') %}
```

If you need the sorted results in the opposite order, you can just apply the `|reverse` filter, i.e.

```
{% set resultsByPlayerHeight = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{playerHeight}')|reverse %}
```

If e.g. `playerPosition` is a relational field (a category, perhaps), you'll need to do something like this:

```
{% set resultsByPlayerPosition = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{{ playerPosition.first.title }}') %}
```